# why is ( 0 < v.size()-1 ) when the vector v is empty?

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector

I wrote the following code. And it's giving unexpected results!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<int> v;

  if(0 < (v.size() - 1))
    cout << "entered" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If we print `v.size()` it prints 0. But still it enters the if condition! why so??

Comment: Because of an historical C++ language design mistake!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`v.size()` has an unsigned return type. Subtracting 1 from an unsigned 0 results in wrap around to some "very large" unsigned number (this is modulo arithmetic).

0 will be less than some "very large" number, always.

It's a common gotcha when working with standard containers and mixing signed/unsigned indices/sizes.

Comment: The "very large" number that results from subtracting 1 from unsigned zero, is the maximum value - which will be positive - that the unsigned return type can represent.

Answer (score 1):

`v.size()` returns a value of unsigned type, so subtracting one will cause it to underflow.

In particular, it is documented as returning `size_type` which is typically typedef'd to be `size_t`, which is unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

`v.size()` is an **`unsigned`** integer value. If you **make it go below zero**, like here, **you get a very large positive number**, because of how *unsigned integers* are represented in memory.

Hence `0<(v.size()-1)` is true indeed.

Just for experimentation, you could have casted to a *signed* `int` and see that now you get the negatives value you expected from the conditional expression:

```
if(0<(static_cast<int>(v.size())-1))
```

Like this the code will enter the condition.