# -1<something doesn't run in while loop

Tags: c++

While solving Today's [leetcode Daily challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-subarrays-with-fixed-bounds/)  I wrote this code: (not the actual solution)

```
class Solution {
public:
    long long countSubarrays(vector<int>& nums, int minK, int maxK) {
        int  j = -1;
        int mintillnow = INT_MAX;
        int maxtillnow = INT_MIN;
        long long  count = 0;
        
            
        while(j<nums.size()){
            cout<<"why not running"<<endl;
            j++;
            mintillnow = min(nums[j],mintillnow);
            maxtillnow = max(nums[j],maxtillnow);
            if(mintillnow==minK && maxtillnow == maxK){
                count++;
            }
            if(mintillnow<minK || maxtillnow>maxK){
               mintillnow = INT_MAX;
               maxtillnow = INT_MIN;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
};
```

The problem is when I initialize j = -1, the loop doesn't run and just returns count.
But the loop works fine when I initialize j = 0 .

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please don't use "competition" sites like that to learn the basics of programming or languages, that's not their purpose. And it simply doesn't work. Please invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++ properly instead.

Comment: duplicates: [Why sizeof(int) is not greater than -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24466857/995714), [why is `0 < v.size()-1` when the vector v is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51914679/995714)

Comment: Why do you have compiler warnings disabled?  Your compiler would tell you what is problematic with this code, if you allowed it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `nums.size()` returns a value that is *unsigned*. That means `j` will also be converted to an unsigned integer type. And `-1` as unsigned is *very* large.

So the condition is simply never true.

Answer (score 0):

Since `j` and `nums.size()` are of different type, they are subject to [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) so that they become of the same type.
Since they are both integer, the most precise one is chosen: in this case you most likely have `int` and `size_t`, and the language considers `size_t` the most precise of the two.

Hence `-1` is converted to `size_t` and will end up being the max possible value for `size_t` (thus your `while` guard is always false)